# fill ComboBox with items from different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, viewmodel

I have a ComboBox binded to DataContext SceneViewModel, but I want to fill it with data from an observableCollection from another ViewModel called GearViewModel.
How do I do this? or is this possible.

Here is the xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MoviePrepper.View.SceneView"
 DataContext="{Binding SceneViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding to observableCollection in GearViewModel}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SceneCollectionView/Equipment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Do you need to bind your `ComboBox` to two `ObservableCollection` (one in `SceneViewModel` and another one in `GearViewModel`)? Or just to bind items to `GearViewModel ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Bind to items in GearViewModel ObservableCollection

Comment: So if you want to use MVVM in the right way, you need to have a `GearViewModel` in your `SceneViewModel`

Comment: And How do I do this the right way? I tried this: var fillComboBox = new GearViewModel(); items= fillComboBox.FillGearComboBox(); items returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a binding like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GearViewModel.MyCollection, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Equipment, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Where the `ItemsSource` property binds to the `GearViewModel.MyCollection` property in your `Locator`, and the `SelectedItem` binds to the `SceneViewModel.Equipment` (as set by the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`).

It is not clear exactly what property you had in mind for binding on the `SelectedItem` property, so I made some assumptions.

Anywho, that should solve the problem with binding your `ItemsSource` property to a different view model.